# Memory leaks and JSON data

Tags: json, delphi, memory-leaks

[image]

I have an app that reads a JSON data string from disk to create a string grid listing stocks (ticker, number held, cost) and then calls a stockbroker API to fill in current price and value.  It works but the code below is causing memory leaks but whilst there are many internet posts on how to access data in a JSONArray none I could find discuss how to free allocated memory.  Can anybody help ?  I use Delphi Berlin 10.1 and Indy 10.6 if it matters.  There are 3 pages of data, some stocks are on 2 pages, sTickers is a stringlist populated with each stock ticker (about 10 of them) and there are about 14 total stock holdings on the 3 stringgrids (tabGrids[0..2] which are on a page control.

The problem code is:

```
      JSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(s) as TJSONArray;
      if JSONarray = nil then
      begin
        ShowMessage('An error occurred reading the data file, section = [' +
                    iniSection[tabpage] + '].');
        continue;
      end;
      for row := 0 to JSONArray.Count - 1 do
      begin
        s := (JSONArray.Items[row] as TJSONObject).Get('ticker').JSONValue.Value;
        SL.Add(s);
      end;
      CombineStrings(sTickers, SL);
      tabGrids[tabpage].RowCount := SL.Count + 2; //set row count
      for row := 1 to SL.Count do
      begin //add fixed data to each grid row
        tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[0, row] := SL[row - 1];
        tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[4, row] := (JSONArray.Items[row - 1] as TJSONObject).Get('qty').JSONValue.Value;
        tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[6, row] := (JSONArray.Items[row - 1] as TJSONObject).Get('cost').JSONValue.Value;
        tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[1, row] := (JSONArray.Items[row - 1] as TJSONObject).Get('name').JSONValue.Value;
        if not tryStrToFloat(tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[4, row], qty) then qty := 0;
        if not tryStrToFloat(tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[6, row], price) then price := 0;
        tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[6, row] := FloatToStr(qty*price/100);
      end;
      tabGrids[tabpage].Width := tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[0] +
        tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[1] + tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[2] +
        tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[3] + tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[4] +
        tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[5] + tabGrids[tabpage].ColWidths[6] + 18;
      SL.Clear;
    end;
    JSONArray.Free;
```

I assume the (JSONArray.Items[row] as TJSONObject).Get('ticker').JSONValue.Value lines are allocating memory that I am not releasing but I do not see how to release it.  Or maybe there is a better way to get the data.

Comment: I can't see how to attach an image here so this link is to a screen shot of the error:https://mega.nz/folder/RxhylBpZ#nxX7cG5zWP8BacA3W110jw.  If I comment out the above code I get no leaks.  I think line 1 calls the constructor but I can find no information on how these JSON calls work with regard to allocating memory. @Tom

Comment: ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True; and I have added an image of the leak report. @Tom

Comment: Well that was a stupid mistake !  I guess I was blind at the time but over several days I never noticed it was outside the loop.  Many thanks for noticing it.@Tom

Comment: You are welcome! You do know, don't you, that you can mark an answer that best answers your question (as **you** decide), as the correct one by clicking the tick mark beside the answer to become green.

Comment: Many thanks - I have done that.    1 question regarding GetValue<string> in your other post.  If you know the value is a number it would be nice to do GetValue<something> where something is 'real' or 'integer' or similar so you do not have to do StrToFloat/StrToInt etc.  I could not find anything that works however. @Tom

Comment: Thanks Lorne. I'm not sure what you mean with "your other post", but please feel free to post a new question regarding `GetValue`. Be however sure to indicate your version 10.1 (as is mine too) as improvements to the Delphi `JSON` library has been made in version 10.3 and those are not beneficial for you (neither me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention 3 pages of data. You are leaking 2 x `TJasonArray`, and you are freeing one `TJasonArray` on the last line right after an `end;` that doesn't have a corresponding begin.

From that I draw the conclusion that you have a loop (that you did not show) that you run three times. On each time you create a `TJasonArray` but you free only one, after the loop `end;`, Move the `JSonArray.Free;` to before the `end;`.

Answer (score 0):

To do it simpler, you can just use a `TJSONValue` to parse and free it at end, without free array :

```
var
  Value: TJsonValue
  // ...
begin
  Value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(s);
  try
    Ar := Value.FindValue('item') as TJSONArray;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Value);
  end;
end;
```

Instead of :

```
tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[1, row] := (JSONArray.Items[row - 1] as TJSONObject).Get('name').JSONValue.Value;
```

You can do

```
tabGrids[tabpage].Cells[1, row] := JSONArray.Items[row - 1].GetValue<string>('name');
```

Then, you have a `end;` before you free the array, if it's a upper loop you will have a memory leaks. Use try finally block to free it and the `TStringList`.